# Opencart failed to echo "shopping_cart" and "checkout" URL in footer.tpl

Tags: php, opencart

I trying to do my own theme by cloning the "default" theme.

I want to add "shopping_cart" and "checkout" Text at the footer.

```
<a href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>">cart</a>

<a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>">checkout</a>
```

**However, I got the following ERROR URL when I click on either "cart" or "checkout" text**

```
http://localhost/oc3/%3Cb%3ENotice%3C/b%3E:%20Undefined%20variable:%20shopping_cart%20in%20%3Cb%3EC:/xampp/htdocs/oc3/catalog/view/theme/gosu/template/common/footer.tpl%3C/b%3E%20on%20line%20%3Cb%3E44%3C/b%3E

http://localhost/oc3/%3Cb%3ENotice%3C/b%3E:%20Undefined%20variable:%20checkout%20in%20%3Cb%3EC:/xampp/htdocs/oc3/catalog/view/theme/gosu/template/common/footer.tpl%3C/b%3E%20on%20line%20%3Cb%3E46%3C/b%3E
```

It's a fresh opencart 2.3.0.2 without modifying anything.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define all the variables you use in a template file (.tpl) in the controller which calls it.  The variables are placed in an array called `$data` which is then extracted and passed to the template so the keys become variable names (i.e. `$data['xyz']` in the controller becomes `$xyz` in the template).

If you are modifying **footer.tpl**, you should edit **/catalog/controller/common/footer.php** and add something like:

```
$data['shopping_cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
$data['checkout'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', true);
```

Comment: thx alot.  btw. How come for the  $data['shopping_cart'],  no need to add " '',true " ? but  for  $data['checkout'] need to add  "true" ?

Comment: `true` generates an link using your SSL url assuming you have it active - if you don't have ssl configured it has no effect.